# ext js 4.2.0.633 - grid column header not showing filter options

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2

filter option in grid column header not working with ext js 4.2.0.633,but works well with extjs-4.1.1

[image]

this is the code i am using

```
Ext.define('Qreda.view.response.DndGrid', 
 extend : 'Qreda.view.BaseRemoteGrid',
 store : 'OptInOutConfigs',
 alias : 'widget.dndgrid',
 frame : true,

initComponent : function() {
this.columns = [{
    header : 'Keyword',
    dataIndex : 'keyword',
    renderer : function(value, metaData, record) {
        return value ? value.name : null;
    },
    filterable : true
    }, {
        header : 'trigger Keyword',
        dataIndex : 'triggerKeyword',
        filterable : true
    }, {
    header : 'Category',
    dataIndex : 'categoryId',
    filter : {
        type : 'list',
        store : Ext.getStore('CgCategories'),
        labelField : 'categoryName'
    }
    }];

    this.callParent();
    this.setTitle('MENU_DND_MANAGEMENT');
    this.on('beforerender', function(component, options) {
        Ext.getStore('CgCategories').load();
    }, this);
}
```

});

someone plase help me to solve this

Comment: please tag your ext js questions with the generic extjs tag - in addition to version tags

Answer (score 1):

Please use the js files for grid filters provided along with the ext js 4.2.0.633 distribution. They can be found in the examples/ux/grid/filter & examples/ux/grid/menu  & ux/grid folders.

Answer (score 0):

Require examples/ux/grid/filter and define it as a feature:

```
// ...
features: [{
    ftype: 'filters'
}]
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The column grid filter plugin is working upto Ext JS 4.1 version.

It's not working for ExtJS 4.2.